# What is different between opencv_world440.dll and opencv_world440d.dll?

Tags: opencv, dll

What is the difference between `**.dll` and `**d.dll`?

Does mean `dynamic` such as a dynamic module?

Or definitely having different contents?

if `**d.dll` mean dynamic module Can I use `opencv_world440.dll` to static link?

[image]

Comment: *d.dll is the debug build of opencv the one without d is the release build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *d.dll is compiled in Debug mode -> therefore its unoptimized and you can place breakpoints in it.

The *.dll is built in release mode and IS optimized -> therefore its recommended for production.

This specifier and dynamic/static linkage have nothing to do with each other!